# ls command with pipes not working when passed into a while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I attempted to execute this command:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd="ls *.txt | sed s/.txt//g"
for i in `$cmd`
do
    echo $i
    echo "Hello world"
done
```

I.e. get things with .txt extension in the current working directory and remove the .txt part from their files and print it out. However, I am getting this error and it appears that ls is interpretting "|" and "sed" and "s/.txt//g" as literal file names:

```
ls: s/.txt//g: No such file or directory
ls: sed: No such file or directory
ls: |: No such file or directory
```

If I pass the command as,  `for i in ls *.txt | sed s/.txt//g`, this is not a problem. Can I get some suggestions?

Comment: Don't store commands in variables. Variables are for data, not executable code or shell syntax. If you need to store a command, use a function, that's what they're for. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: As an aside, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: `for f in *.txt; do i=${f%.txt}; ...; done`.

Comment: Also, this is a `sh` script, not a bash script. Bash scripts need to start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

- If you want this to be a bash script, not a sh script, you need to change the shebang to invoke bash.
- The immediate reason evaluating `$cmd` does not behave identically to running a command with `cmd`'s contents is described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).
- Also see [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) describing why `eval` is prone to causing security risks.
- The shell has its own built-in string substitution behavior; there's no reason to use `sed`. See [the bash-hackers' wiki page on parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) describing how `${var%suffix}` expands to the contents of `$var` with `suffix` removed.
- In `ls *.txt`, it's not `ls` that evaluates the `*.txt` glob: *The shell itself does that, before starting the `ls` executable*. As such, there's no point to running `ls` at all: It's the shell's built-in functionality that generates the list of filenames, so you might as well just use that list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in *.txt; do i=${i%.txt}
    echo "$i"
    echo "Hello world"
done
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, that string substitution method looks very useful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(ls *.txt | sed s/.txt//g)
do
    echo $i
    echo "Hello world"
done
```

Simple and works.

Answer (score -2):

The basic issue is the sequence of expansion (see EXPANSION in man bash):

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion,
> parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution
> (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname
> expansion.

In other words, the command substitution already assumed that the original line was split into individual commands, and it will not recognize '|', ';', and other bash keywords.

If the command is constant, the simple solution is to inline it:

```
for i in `ls *.txt | sed s/.txt//g`
```

From the OP, looks like the command has to be variable. In this case, one can use 'eval' to force re-parsing of the variable into the pipeline:

```
for i in `eval $cmd`
```

Make sure to read all the warning about using "eval", and constructing commands on the fly.

Minor comment: In `sed` the command 's/.txt//g' assumes that `.txt` is regular expression. Therefore, it will change `btxt.txt` to `.txt`. Make sure to escape the '.' so that it will be treated as literal.

```
cmd="ls *.txt | sed -e 's/\.txt//g'
```

Comment: Many of the examples here are bad practice. `for i in $(eval $cmd)` string-splits and glob-expands the command before joining it back on spaces and then sending it to `eval`; to ensure that you're `eval`ing it as-given it would need to be `$(eval "$cmd")`, but even then, `for i in $(...anything...)` is _itself_ bad practice for the reasons given in [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: In particular, with `eval $cmd`, the glob `*.txt` is expanded **before** `eval` runs, so a file named `$(rm -rf ~).txt` can delete your home directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I agree with all those comments. There is not enough information in the OP to figure out how to implement safe production-quality solution. My solution address some of the issues, but it's definitely not production ready. I believe it's better (and more correct) vs. the code in the OP.